# Symfony2 : Embedded form validation is not triggered when editing

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony2-easyadmin

**Symfony version :** 2.8.5

**Context:** I have an entity `Restaurant` which has a OneToOne relationship  with an entity `Coordinates` which have several relations with other entities related to Coordinates informations. I my backend I create a form related to `Restaurant` entity with a custom nested form related to `Coordinates`.

Nota : I use [EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle) to generate my backend.

**Entities relations scheme :**

`Restaurant`

```
  1 ________ 1 `Coordinates`
                    * ________ 1 `CoordinatesCountry`
                    1 ________ 1 `CoordinatesFR`
                                      * ________ 1 `CoordinatesFRLane`
                                      * ________ 1 `CoordinatesFRCity`
```

**Backend view :**

[image]

**At this point I try the following scenario :**

1. I create a new Restaurant, so I fill the fields related form for the first time. I let the `Coordinates` nested form blank (empty fields). So after form submission, validation messages are displayed (see image below).

[image]

2. I edit the previous form and this time I fill the fields of the `Coordinates` nested form. After form submission, a new `Coordinates` entity is hydrated and a relationship is created between `Restaurant` and `Coordinates`.
3. Once again I edit the previous form and this time I clear all the fields of the `Coordinates` nested form. The validation is not triggered and I get the following error :

> Expected argument of type "FBN\GuideBundle\Entity\CoordinatesFRCity",
>   "NULL" given

I precise that in `CoordinatesFRType` (see code below), to trigger the validations message the first time I had to use the option `empty_data` with a closure (like described in the [official doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/use_empty_data.html#option-2-provide-a-closure)) to instatiate a new `CoordinatesFR` instance in case of empty datas (all fields blank). But [here](https://webmozart.io/blog/2015/09/09/value-objects-in-symfony-forms/), in this article (written by the creator of the Symfony form component), it is explained (see empty_data and datta mappers paragraphs) that the `empty_data` is only called at object creation. So I think this the reason why my validation does not work anymore in case of edition.

**Question** : why the validation is not effective anymore when editing my form and clearing all embedded form ?

**The code (only what is necessary) :**

*Restaurant entity*

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Restaurant
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FBN\GuideBundle\Entity\Coordinates", inversedBy="restaurant", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $coordinates;
}
```

*Coordinates entity*

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Coordinates
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FBN\GuideBundle\Entity\CoordinatesCountry")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $coordinatesCountry;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FBN\GuideBundle\Entity\CoordinatesFR", inversedBy="coordinates", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $coordinatesFR;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FBN\GuideBundle\Entity\Restaurant", mappedBy="coordinates")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $restaurant;
}
```

*CoordinatesFR entity*

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class CoordinatesFR extends CoordinatesISO
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FBN\GuideBundle\Entity\CoordinatesFRLane")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
    * @Assert\NotBlank()
    */
   private $coordinatesFRLane;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FBN\GuideBundle\Entity\CoordinatesFRCity")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    * @Assert\NotBlank()
    */
   private $coordinatesFRCity;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FBN\GuideBundle\Entity\Coordinates", mappedBy="coordinatesFR")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $coordinates;
}
```

*Easy Admin config (equivalent to RestaurantType)*

```yml
easy_admin:
    entities:
        Restaurant:
            class : FBN\GuideBundle\Entity\Restaurant
            form:
                fields:
                    - { property: 'coordinates', type: 'FBN\GuideBundle\Form\CoordinatesType' }
```

*CoordinatesType*

```php
class CoordinatesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('CoordinatesCountry', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'FBNGuideBundle:CoordinatesCountry',
                'property' => 'country',
                ))
            ->add('coordinatesFR', CoordinatesFRType::class)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'FBN\GuideBundle\Entity\Coordinates',
        ));
    }
}
```

*CoordinatesFRType*

```php
class CoordinatesFRType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('laneNum', TextType::class)
            ->add('coordinatesFRLane', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'FBNGuideBundle:CoordinatesFRLane',
                'property' => 'lane',
                'placeholder' => 'label.form.empty_value',
                ))
            ->add('laneName', TextType::class)
            ->add('miscellaneous', TextType::class)
            ->add('locality', TextType::class)
            ->add('metro', TextType::class)
            ->add('coordinatesFRCity', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'FBNGuideBundle:CoordinatesFRCity',
                'property' => 'display',
                'query_builder' => function (CoordinatesFRCityRepository $repo) {
                    return $repo->getAscendingSortedCitiesQueryBuilder();
                    },
                'placeholder' => 'label.form.empty_value',
                ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'FBN\GuideBundle\Entity\CoordinatesFR',
            // Ensures that validation error messages will be correctly displayed next to each field 
            // of the corresponding nested form (i.e if submission and CoordinatesFR nested form with all fields empty)
            'empty_data' => function (FormInterface $form) {
                return new CoordFR();
            },
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be related to a clash between your entity validity and what the form wants to put in there. I can advice you to read http://blog.iltar.nl/posts/733915-avoiding-entities-in-forms

Comment: @Anyone Thanks, it is a very interesting post. Don't you think that a workaround to solve my issue could be to implement a custom data mapper and in the mapFormsToData() method to instatiate a new `CoordinatesFR` object in case of edition ?

Comment: I think the easiest would be to blindly put all form data in either an array or DTO and when valid put it in your entity, that's the easiest solution to avoid having to nest yourself into data hydration behavior

Comment: @Anyone Yes it's a solution using what we could name an intermediary.

Comment: @Anyone The DTO solution is also evocated by Stof in this [post](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17003). He also proposes to allow null values in setters.

Comment: While allowing null values are an easy solution and a quick win for this problem, it will not work for a long term solution

Comment: There is nothing to deal with easyadminbundle. You should use 'cascade_validation' => true, in CoordinatesFRType under setDefaultOptions function.